# How to change key in dictionary

Tags: python

So, I have some dictionary, which keys got mixed up and I want to delete its keys and put new key in it.
First problem I have is that, i dont really know how to change key, but I deleted them and tried to make new keys again, however it says that dictionary changed size, even thought its the same. 
Second problem is that, if I write/add keys like that, I want it to be simple, not like adding one key at one time.

```
Journal = {12: 'ASUS', 2: 'HP', 57: 'IBM', 3: 'DELL', 689: 'APPLE'}

bb = ('pc', 'computer', 'notebook', 'inovation' 'something', 'sdsd')
for keys, values in Journal.items():
  if keys not in bb:
    print("change")
  del Journal[keys]
  Journal[bb[0]] = "ASUS"
  Journal[bb[1]] = "HP"
  Journal[bb[2]] = "IBM"
  Journal[bb[3]] = "DELL"
  Journal[bb[4]] = "APPLE"    

print(Journal)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the link to Python's [dictionary documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesmapping). In almost all cases this will provide the answers you are looking for.

It's difficult to understand exactly what your problem is without more source code, but here's my approach to what I think you're trying to achieve:

```
for k, v in Journal.items():
    if k not in bb:
        del Journal[k]

Journal[ bb[0] ] = "ASUS"
Journal[ bb[1] ] = "HP"
Journal[ bb[2] ] = "IBM"
Journal[ bb[3] ] = "DELL"
Journal[ bb[4] ] = "APPLE"
```

The only way to do this faster is if you already know the values of the list bb and initialize the dictionary with them directly, but without seeing more code it's unclear if this fits your use case.

```
Journal = { 
    "TheValueOfbb0" : "ASUS",
    "TheValueOfbb1" : "HP",
    "TheValueOfbb2" : "IBM" }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the error because you're modifying the dictionary at the same time as you're iterating over it.

You can avoid the problem by converting the iterator `items()` returns into a list of items, and then iterator over that. This only requires changing one line:

```
for keys, values in list(Journal.items()):
```